# kubernetes jenkins-plugins - JnlpProtocol3 is disabled by default, use JNLP_PROTOCOL_OPTS to alter the behavior

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to configure Jenkin on my kubernetes cluster following steps from here https://radu-matei.com/blog/kubernetes-jenkins-azure/

from the slave I see JNLP Disabled not sure where I need to set this variable, tried in Jenkins global environment variable setting, it didn't work.

How can I set this variable?

```
Warning: JnlpProtocol3 is disabled by default, use JNLP_PROTOCOL_OPTS to alter the behavior
Warning: SECRET is defined twice in command-line arguments and the environment variable
Warning: AGENT_NAME is defined twice in command-line arguments and the environment variable
```

[image]

Here is my jenkin configuration. 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should change Jenkins URL to `serviceName` and use port 8080, something like this:

```
http://jenkins.default.svc.cluster.local:8080
```

Comment: @camille That link *is* the answer.  The poster is suggesting to change a property of the Jenkins configuration to a URL and then gave an example of what to change it to.  The URL doesn't actually go anywhere.